# Colors look different on my website

Tags: html, css, colors, web

So all grays look different on my website. They look kind of yellow-ish. I don't know why this is happening. I tried checking in htmlcolorcodes.com bevause at first I thought my computer was the problem but in htmlcolorcodes grays look normal. I already tried with the same HEX code.

HEX CODE that I'm using: #f0f0f0 (although I'm having this problem with all different variations of gray)

```
.charts:hover {
background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.chartPos {
width: 3.5%;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
border-right: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
}
```

A friend tried on his end and the color loaded correctly. This problem is driving me crazy please help me.

[image: This is how it looks on my end.]
How it looks in my computer; I already tried using Google Chrome and Safari.
[image]
How it should look. (also on my computer)

To check if you see the color correctly or the same way as me the website is available here [Spredt.com](http://www.spredt.com/charts)

Comment: I don't see any yellow in your screenshot...

Comment: I just updated the question so you can see the difference.

Comment: The screen could be not good calibrated (so yellow casts), and colour adaptation + colour at edges affect how we see colours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they're the same colour. Take a screenshot then use a color-picker in Paint or something.

Both of your examples posted here return #F0F0F0, and if you cut and paste your example of how it **should** look over how it *does* look, you'll see the colours are identical.

I believe it may be the lighter grey behind it that makes it look yellow-ish.

Comment: Agreed, they are the same color (#F0F0F0). The gray behind is slightly blue (#FAF9FF), which makes the gray on top look relatively yellowish.